# Understanding how to move a trail along a path that changes

Tags: java

So my question is pretty simple... but getting it to work like that is another story. So I'll dig right in!

Objective: I'm trying to make a snake like game and I'm having issues with the trail following the path. I've used previous methods that DID work, however, I'm trying to eliminate the "destination" object so the snake has a free move feel instead of a grid feel.

My issue is when I started rewriting my player class, I got rid of a lot of redundant stuff. My final task is to fix how the trail moves. I'm wanting the trail to follow its trail by sliding into position.

The code I have written that works before (Grid-feel):

```
public void Move(int delta){
 //        double moveSpeed = (delta * .6f) - (oreWeight * ore + armorWeight * armor);

        //Smooth animation for snake movement
        if(IsMoving() && (X.equals(destX) && Y.equals(destY)) ){
            for(int i = 1; i < getSize(); i++){
                if(destX.get(i).intValue() != X.get(i-1).intValue()){
                    destX.set(i, X.get(i-1));
                }
                else if(destY.get(i).intValue() != Y.get(i-1).intValue()){
                    destY.set(i, Y.get(i-1));
                }
            }

            if(left){
                destX.set(0, destX.get(0) - GameBoardNew.blockSize);
            }
            else if(right){
                destX.set(0, destX.get(0) + GameBoardNew.blockSize);
            }
            else if(up){
                destY.set(0, destY.get(0) - GameBoardNew.blockSize);
            }
            else if(down){
                destY.set(0, destY.get(0) + GameBoardNew.blockSize);
            }
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++){
                if(up || down){
                    if(X.get(i).intValue() != destX.get(i).intValue()){
                        X.set(i, X.get(i) + Integer.signum(destX.get(i) - X.get(i)));
                    }
                    else if(Y.get(i).intValue() != destY.get(i).intValue()){
                        Y.set(i, Y.get(i) + Integer.signum(destY.get(i) - Y.get(i)));
                    }
                }
                if(right || left){
                    if(Y.get(i).intValue() != destY.get(i).intValue()){
                        Y.set(i, Y.get(i) + Integer.signum(destY.get(i) - Y.get(i)));
                    }
                    else if(X.get(i).intValue() != destX.get(i).intValue()){
                        X.set(i, X.get(i) + Integer.signum(destX.get(i) - X.get(i)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And now, since I have reworked it, I am adding in a velocity of how fast the player is traveling along with other conditions, along with trying to get rid of the destination part of the formula and using its body as a way to figure that out. However, what I have, works, until the player moves around fast in different directions... then the body just clumps up together. Its essentially the same formula, but still very puzzled.

```
public void Move(int delta){
 //        float moveSpeed = (playerSpeed - (oreWeight * getSize() + armorWeight * armor)) * delta;
    float moveSpeed = 1f;

    if(IsMoving() && player.get(0).getX() == playerDest.get(0).getX()){
        for(int i = 1; i < getSize(); i++){
            if(playerDest.get(i).getX() != player.get(i - 1).getX()){
                playerDest.get(i).setX(player.get(i - 1).getX());
            }
            else{
                playerDest.get(i).setY(player.get(i - 1).getY());
            }
        }

        if(left){
            playerDest.get(0).setX(player.get(0).getX() - moveSpeed);
        }
        else if(right){
            playerDest.get(0).setX(player.get(0).getX() + moveSpeed);
        }
        else if(up){
            playerDest.get(0).setY(player.get(0).getY() - moveSpeed);
        }
        else if(down){
            playerDest.get(0).setY(player.get(0).getY() + moveSpeed);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++){
        Rectangle location = player.get(i);
        Rectangle inFront = playerDest.get(i);
        int xVel = Integer.signum((int)inFront.getX() - (int)location.getX());
        int yVel = Integer.signum((int)inFront.getY() - (int)location.getY());
        if(up || down){
            if(location.getX() != inFront.getX()){
                if(xVel == 1){
                    location.setX(location.getX() + moveSpeed);
                }
                else if(xVel == -1){
                    location.setX(location.getX() - moveSpeed);
                }
            }
            else if(location.getY() != inFront.getY()){
                if(yVel == 1){
                    location.setY(location.getY() + moveSpeed);
                }
                else if(yVel == -1){
                    location.setY(location.getY() - moveSpeed);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(right || left){
            if(location.getY() != inFront.getY()){
                if(yVel == 1){
                    location.setY(location.getY() + moveSpeed);
                }
                else if(yVel == -1){
                    location.setY(location.getY() - moveSpeed);
                }
            }
            else if(location.getX() != inFront.getX()){
                if(xVel == 1){
                    location.setX(location.getX() + moveSpeed);
                }
                else if(xVel == -1){
                    location.setX(location.getX() - moveSpeed);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I do need to clarify any information, I will be glad; just ask!

Thank you for taking your time to read this!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "grid-feel"?  Any time you use distinct numbers like integers it produces a grid-like environment.  Discrete data types like floats (i.e., decimals) are generally used for a "free-moving" system.

Comment: My meaning of grid-feel, The player's destination was set to it's size, so for instance this was 20 px. So the player would have to move 20px before it would accept a different direction. Just updated the main post with the full method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By another help forum, people recommend to use a destination object to follow the previous object in a trail to avoid a glitch path finding.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a snake with segmented body have each segment follow the segment before it. The only segment that has "free will" is the head which follows the user input.

Comment: That is true. The head is the only part that accepts input from the user to move the head. The other pieces are just following in a line behind each other.

Comment: So, having this in mind, shouldnt you be able to 'decay' tiles in a [WireWorld](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireworld) way? Obviously, it's tricky to get it right when there are tiles next to each other...

Comment: Tralli I just reread your answer and yes, that is how it is supposed to work. But if I wasn't having issues trying to get it to work like that, then I wouldn't have posted the question to get some help =).

@StackOverflowException What do you mean?

Comment: You are always working on a grid, it just depends on how small the it is in pixels. You have a timer that runs on X intervals, on interval N you move the head, on N+1 the first body segment imitates the head movement, on N+2 the second body segment imitates the first segment movement etc.

Comment: @Tralli I am not using a timer. I am using a float value that is being passed into the method in order to move the body and the trial pieces. I do understand the concept of how to move the body, but I'm confused why its not working correctly.